# Cyclic arbitrage with multiple graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I have a working solution of cyclic arbitrage using Bellman-Ford algorithm which focuses on 1 exchange. Now I would like to expand this to multiple exchanges. Like that. Green and Blue are different exchanges

[image]

- I would like to find the best path (highest profit)
- Ideally minimising the jump between exchanges

As an example:

[image]

How would I best approach this? I was thinking of linking i.e the green CHF vertex with the blue USD one with the same edge weight as the blue CHF->USD and I would do that for both directions and all vertices?

Comment: Should it be that the *edges* are coloured instead of the *vertices*?

Comment: Anyways, if we ignore the constraint of "minimising the jump between exchanges", the optimal solution would be to merge the two graphs, and replace the adjacency matrix by $C_{i, j} = \min(A_{i, j}, B_{i, j})$ for each edge $i \to j$.

Comment: thanks that is actually a good approach. Makes the graph a lot smaller.